# nested if: too many arguments?

Tags: bash, shell

For some reason this code creates problems:

```
source="/foo/bar/"
destination="/home/oni/"

if [ -d $source ]; then
        echo "Source directory exists"
        if [ -d $destination ]; then
                echo "Destination directory exists"
                rsync -raz --delete --ignore-existing --ignore-times --size-only --stats --progress $source $destination
                chmod -R 0755 $destination
        else
                echo "Destination directory does not exists"
        fi
else
        echo "Source directory does not exists"
fi
```

It errors out with:

```
Source directory exists
/usr/bin/copyfoo: line 7: [: too many arguments
Destination directory does not exists
```

I used nested if statements in bash before without a problem, what simple mistake am I overlooking?

Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem, and couldn't get the if-statement to work as it should using -z, -n or =. The solution to my problem was the following: I had used echo and find to set a variable. I wanted to see if "find" had found anything. I echoed the variable and got nothing, so I assumed it was empty. But I then echoed the length of the string using ${#string_name} and saw that it was of length 2. Meaning it contained 2 whitespace chars. So I changed my if to check for length 2 (since all my correct answers would be longer). You could also check for 2 whitespaces. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax really looks correct. Works in dash/bash.

Did you change the name of the destination directory for this example? If your real name contains e.g. whitespace you're better off quoting the tested variable.

```
if [ -d "$destination" ]; then
```

(I would leave the destination-directory-check anyway as rsync will create the directory if its missing. If you copy on the same computer and not over a network, I would leave the -z compression parameter of rsync also.)

**Update:**

Does this work for you? (You'll have to change paths)

```
#!/bin/bash

source="/tmp/bar/"
destination="/tmp/baz/"

test -d "$source" || {
    echo "$source does not exist"
    exit
}

rsync -ra \
--delete \
--ignore-existing --ignore-times --size-only \
--stats --progress "$source" "$destination"

if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Failure exit value: $?"
fi
```

Comment: Sorry man, Mikel was a bit earlier. Thanks for the suggestion though! I still need help with since it says now that the folder doesn't exist when wrapping double quotes.

Comment: No I was earlier ;-) - Test: when you place a `test -d "$destination" || { echo "$destination does not exist"; exit }` right after the path assignements, does it really exit then?

Comment: My apologies initall, since it only mentions it in hours it confuses me sometimes. Anyway, when I add that line just beneath the path assignments I get line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: I think initall beat me.  When I posted mine then reloaded, initall's said "answered 2 mins ago".  I was typing my answer on my mobile phone.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your `destination` is set to something different than you showed us above, probably something containing whitespace.

You should put double quotes around it in the `[ ]` block too, e.g. `[ -d "$destination" ]`.

Comment: Very nice deducing :-) I am using whitespace. I changed it to put double quotes around it but now it says that the folder does not exist, even though it does.

Comment: You need to put double quotes around `$source` and `$destination` everywhere it appears in the script.